# How to add Sticky Note to Right Click-->"New" Menu

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, shortcuts, context-menu, right-click

I'm talking about the menu that appears when you right-click on the desktop. Then if you look in the list there should be something labeled "New", and when you hover over this it shows you options such as folder, shortcut etc.

I know that you can add an entry to this menu.  However, I have not been able to accomplish this with the Sticky Notes (.snt) file.  I know how to add Sticky Notes to the context menu; I just want to move it under the "new" tab. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to add a (the?) sticky notes application to the context menu?  Unless you are talking about a special application that associates a sticky note with a file, or copies text from a document file into a sticky note, there wouldn't be a "context" to associate with a file.  Are you just looking for a way to quick-launch a sticky note (that can be done from the system tray)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I wish to add the application "sticky note" to the right click context menu (in the desktop) under the "new" option. Hope that clarified what I want

Comment: The context menu is not a general purpose launcher.  It is limited to doing things specific to the context of the object or application space you are right-clicking in, typically where the object or application can be passed as a command line argument to the program you want to do something.  If Sticky Notes didn't come with a context menu installer, it will need to be capable of accepting command line arguments.  Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: @fixer1234 I know how to add it to the context menu, I just want to move it under the "new" tab

Answer (score 0):

I have found a easy to follow guide [HERE](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/).

For this to work you need to open "regedit.exe and add a registry key in:     HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell and make a new key under the shell key and name it what program you want to add, next make a new folder under the newly created one called "command" add a new key in there with the full path of the program you want to launch.

UPDATE, I found another small guide which is a lot to put on [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-items-from-new-context-menu) so here it is. You use a program called ShellNewHandler.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he already knows how to get the program on the right click menu.  He's looking specifically to put in under "New".

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, that's right, I already know  to add it in the normal context menu, however I have had a hard time just somehow moving that entry underneath the "new" section, quite frustrating really...

Comment: Yeah registry can be tricky, Personally I do not know the location for this. All you have to to is find where the right click new menu is stored in the Registry.